# Separate authentication server just for mobile

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0, access-token, keycloak, refresh-token

We have a situation with our Nativescript Angular App. We use OAuth 2 with PKCE for our authentication process but my team is fairly new to the world of mobile development.

From my research it would seem best practice suggests the lifespan of the refresh token should be anywhere between 2 weeks and 2 months. Currently our access token lifespan is set to 2 minutes and our refresh token lifespan is 30 mins. This means our users have to login every 30 mins using their username and password which isn't ideal for UX and we've received a lot of criticism for it.

Our login page uses a WebView so we considered also trying to auto-populate the form fields with a securely stored version of the username and password but then realised this can't really be done and isn't great for security.

So to improve the login process and make it more seamless, we're looking to setup face/touch ID with a pin code fallback. This means we'll have to push the lifespan of the refresh token to say 2 months or as long as possible — this seems like the best approach moving forward.

That said, the other problem is we also have a website which uses the same authentication server so if we change the Keycloak settings it'll change it also for the website as well which will create more work for the web team.

So my question is should we be using a separate authentication server just for mobile access?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use offline tokens that never expires. Check this https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/index.html#_offline-access

Basically in authentication process you pass additional scope named `offline_access` and instead of regular refresh token auth server returns offline token.

> So my question is should we be using a separate authentication server just for mobile access?

If you use separate server (realm) for mobile app then you will have separate user, client and session collections and you will have hard time integrating additional applications with auth server.